# iterating through multidimensional array to store index/coordinates of occupied locations in dict using value as key

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I am iterating through a multi-dimensional Python list using a for loop. The list represents a board, and I am looking for occupied spaces. There will always be more than one space for each game piece, which are each represented by an integer.

I want to use that integer as the key and then store occupied coordinates in individual lists as the values of a dictionary. Finally, a third value will be stored in each coordinate that represents its state: `(x, y, state)`.

For example,

```
board = [
    [0, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 0],
]
ships = {}
```

Here is my code:

```
for row in board:
    for column in row:
        if column != 0:
            if column not in ships:
                ships[column] = [[row.index(column), board.index(row), 0]]
            else:
                ships[column].append([row.index(column), board.index(row), 0])
```

I'm not sure why it's adding the same coordinate twice. It should never encounter that coordinate again if it is looping linearly through each row and column.

Comment: What you are currently getting seems incorrect. When I run the code that you provided, I get this as the resulting value of `ships`: `{1: [[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]}`

Comment: yes exactly, it should get different values for the indexes of each instance of 1 on the board

Comment: Then please update your question to clarify

Comment: there is a better example, it is repeating the first coordinate. however, each coordinate should be unique... thank you for your help

Comment: the reason the indexes were wrong in that example is because i needed to manipulate them later but that was not actually an error. the only issue is that it repeats the coordinates. it collects the right number of coordinates but their values are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of the `index()` method. When you write `row.index(column)`, [it returns you the index for the first column it finds that is equal to the one you gave it](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm).
So the problem arises by the fact that you have rows that are equivalent (first and seconds rows for examples, `[0, 0, 1]` and `[0, 0, 1]`.

I suggest you use the [`enumerate()` built-in function](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) to retrieve the indices.

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(board):
    for column_index, column in enumerate(row):
        if column != 0:
            if column not in ships:
                ships[column] = [[column_index, row_index, 0]]
            else:
                ships[column].append([column_index, row_index, 0])
```

Output for

```
board = [
    [0, 0, 1], 
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 2, 0],
]
```

`{1: [[2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]], 2: [[1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0]]}`.

Just a reminder that the indices start from 0.

Comment: for sure, thanks man, its def better for me to use the built in functions in this case. also, i understand the indices start at 0, i was just manipulating them because the board is labeled that way. i really appreciate the help. i have heard of enumerate before but have never really used it so i will study this solution to make sure i really get it!

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.nonzero()` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

board = np.asarray(board)
ships = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in zip(*np.nonzero(board)):
    ships[board[i, j]].append([i, j, 0])

ships
# defaultdict(list, {1: [[0, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]], 2: [[2, 1, 0], [3, 1, 0]]})
```

`np.nonzero(board)` gives a tuple of (rows, columns) at indices where the board is not zero.  For each of these (i, j) combinations, access the corresponding element at the board and append its coordinates to the dictionary with that value as the key.

An alternative with `np.ndenumerate()`:

```
for (row, col), val in np.ndenumerate(board):
    # Introspect this with `list(np.ndenumerate(board))`
    if val != 0:
        ships[val].append([row, col, 0])
```

If you want a Python dictionary, just use `dict(ships)`.

Comment: wow, that is a good way to do this. do you know why the nested for loops failed?
(yay numpy)

Comment: See @Gabriel's answer, he is correct.  `board.index(row)` will get you the first occurence of that row, even though you want the 2nd.